# Windows.UserIdentity.Name is empty after <assemblies><clear />

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-authentication

I have a virtual directory in a big noisy intranet application 
- I need to inherit various appSettings etc from the parent web's web.config 
- I want to decouple runtime dependencies; esp, if an assembly is added to the main site, I don't want to break every sub-application

So I add 'clear' inherited assemblies (handlers and modules) in web.config, as follows...

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
        <clear/>
```

.. etc

However HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is now empty (IsAuthenticated = false, Name = "").

The Windows user seems to be authenticated OK by IIS, as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: you can not totally clear assemblies and wait to work as before. There are many assemblies that you need to keep.

Comment: If `IsAuthenticated` is false then it means that user is not getting authenticated and you are not going to get his/her identity.